# r - tryCatch error handling within Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

**Background**

I am using a shiny app to `cut` and `table` some data.

The dataset is included in the `shiny` code below, but the head is:

```
> head(df_in)
  Report_Year Position   Target
1        2014      CEO 29.27644
2        2014      CEO 29.27644
3        2014      CFO 17.56586
4        2014       CE 17.56586
5        2014      COO 17.56586
6        2014      CEO 46.84231
```

I am using the following statement to `cut` and `table` the data

```
  df <- df_in %>%
    filter(Report_Year == input$v_year,
           Position == "CEO") %>%
    select(Target) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Target)) %>%
    mutate(bins = cut(Target, breaks=seq(0, (max(Target)+25), 25))) %>%
    select(bins) %>%
    table %>%
    as.data.frame

>
         . Freq
1   (0,25]    0
2  (25,50]    6
3  (50,75]    2
4 (75,100]    1
```

In the data there are **no** entries for `Report_Year == 2012`, so when the user selects `2012` I want it to either display a message like 'no data' or at the moment I'd be happy with an empty data frame.

I have tried a `tryCatch()` statement but I'm obviously not doing it correctly as the app crashes when the user selects `2012`.

**Question**

How should I be writing the `tryCatch`?

**Shiny App**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("v_year", label = "select year", choices = c(2012, 2014), selected = 2014)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("dt")
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {


df <- reactive({

  ## data
  df_in <- structure(list(Report_Year = c(2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
  2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
  2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
  2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L), Position = c("CEO", 
  "CEO", "CFO", "CE", "COO", "CEO", "CFO", "BUE", "CE", "CFO", 
  "CEO", "COO", "CE", "BUE", "COO", "CFO", "CE", "GC", "CEO", "CEO", 
  "CE", "BUE", "CEO", "CFO", "CE", "GC", "CFO", "CEO", "CEO", "CE"
  ), Target = c(29.2764408921928, 29.2764408921928, 17.5658645353157, 
  17.5658645353157, 17.5658645353157, 46.8423054275084, 38.6449019776945, 
  38.6449019776945, 38.6449019776945, 35.1317290706313, 35.1317290706313, 
  46.8423054275084, 35.1317290706313, 35.1317290706313, 43.9146613382892, 
  43.9146613382892, 35.1317290706313, 35.1317290706313, 29.2764408921928, 
  87.8293226765783, 11.7105763568771, 11.7105763568771, 29.2764408921928, 
  17.5658645353157, 35.1317290706313, 40.9870172490699, 40.9870172490699, 
  73.1911022304819, 70.2634581412627, 46.8423054275084)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Report_Year", 
  "Position", "Target"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))

    tryCatch({
      df <- df_in %>%
        filter(Report_Year == input$v_year,
               Position == "CEO") %>%
        select(Target) %>%
        filter(!is.na(Target)) %>%
        mutate(bins = cut(Target, breaks=seq(0, (max(Target)+25), 25))) %>%
        select(bins) %>%
        table %>%
        as.data.frame
    }, 
    warning=function(w) { 
      print("Warning")
      df <- data.frame()
      return(NA)
    }, 
    error=function(e) {
      print("Error")
      df <- data.frame()
      return(NULL)
    }
    )
})

output$dt <- renderDataTable({
  df  <- df()
})

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Session Info**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_AU.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_AU.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] knitr_1.10.5   rmarkdown_0.7  stringr_1.0.0  extrafont_0.17 scales_0.2.5   tidyr_0.2.0    ggplot2_1.0.1  reshape2_1.4.1
 [9] dplyr_0.4.2    shiny_0.12.1
```

**Error Message**

[image: appRErrorMessage]

Comment: Your app works fine for me. It doesnt crash when I choose 2012..

Comment: @LyzandeR oh. I'm running it through RStudio, you?

Comment: I am using Rstudio too.

Comment: @LyzandeR That's odd. I've added my session info too in case that can shed any light

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: @LyzandeR image attached - the 'crash' occurs when I select `2012`, the app exits and the Error shown is `Error: 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite'`

Comment: Have you uploaded here your full data set? I am pretty sure that the error comes from `seq`. If you do ?seq you will see that there is a `from` and a `to` argument. It seems that the `to` argument is NA or NAN or Inf in your data set. If you fix this it will work.

Comment: @LyzandeR the data here is complete and not generated with `seq`. However,  I am using `seq` in my `mutate` call. This wouldn't explain why my app crashes and yours doesn't though would it?

Comment: Yeah I was referring to `seq` in your mutate call but if your data set is complete this shouldn't be the cause of the error. I can see that you re calling the app from your directory so does this mean you have a server.r and a ui.r in your directory? If you copy paste your code in your post and try running it, does it work?

Comment: @LyzandeR the single-file `app.R` code here is a subset of a much larger app which uses a `server.R` and `ui.R`. I've saved app.R in a temp directory on my desktop to test this chunk of code, as it was also causing my larger app to crash. I have copied and pasted this code into a new session and it still crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    df_in <- structure(...) # As before

    # Filter data according to input$v_year
    df <- reactive({
        df_in %>%
            filter(Report_Year == input$v_year, Position == "CEO") %>%
            select(Target) %>%
            filter(!is.na(Target))
    })

    # Prepare bins or return if df is empty
    bins <- reactive({
        if(nrow(df()) == 0) return()
        df() %>%
            mutate(bins = cut(Target, breaks=seq(0, (max(Target)+25), 25))) %>%
            select(bins) %>%
            table %>%
            as.data.frame
    })

    output$dt <- renderDataTable({
        bins()
    })        
})
```

Since we check if `df()` is empty as long as your input is correct `seq` will never receive an empty argument.

Comment: Yeah that might be the approach I'll have to take. Using my original code, does your app crash when the user selects 2012?

Comment: Generally speaking I will argue that checking input is something you should do in Shiny anyway, not only to contain possible sources of errors but to avoid unnecessary propagation of changes.

Comment: Thanks for the 'known bug' link. I might change the question to make it about the crash/known bug instead.