# How to catch all errors from Shiny module call?

Tags: r, error-handling, shiny, user-experience

I want to wrap Shiny module in kind of "try catch" to prevent it from crashing in any unexpected way. Module represents one of `shinydashboard` tabs, so the app is still usable after one of components fails.

I'm aware of possibility of using `req` function not to stop the application after single error (proposed e.g. in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366101/r-trycatch-error-handling-within-shiny) post) but the goal here is to achieve quick win by reducing user cost of errors for quite complex app with a substantial technical debt.

Expected behaviour: after module crash modal is shown but user can still use the app.

Reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

counterButton <- function(id, label = "Counter") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("button"), label = label),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("out"))
  )
}

counter <- function(input, output, session) {
  count <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    count(count() + 1)
    stop("Test observeEvent error")
  })
  output$out <- renderText({
    count()
  })
  count
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  counterButton("counter1", "Counter #1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  tryCatch({
    callModule(counter, "counter1")
  }, error = function(err) {
    showNotification(paste("Error: ", err$message), type = "error")}
  )}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've found a partial solution (see [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/prevent-observer-crashes/25169/2)) and it indeed works but it involves changes in application modules code, which is not always possible for me to do:

```
tryObserveEvent <- function(eventExpr, handlerExpr, ...) {
  eventExpr <- substitute(eventExpr)
  handlerExpr <- substitute(handlerExpr)

  env <- parent.frame()

  shiny::observeEvent(tryCatch(
    eval(eventExpr, env),
    error = function(e) {
      showNotification(paste("Error: ", e$message), type = "error")
    }
  ),
  {
    tryCatch(
      eval(handlerExpr, env),
      error = function(e) {
        showNotification(paste("Error: ", e$message), type = "error")
      }
    )
  }, ...)
}
```

[image: popup]

Answer (score 0):

Recently I came across the same need. This is a small try for your example. Hope it helps. It helped me, to at least start working on a good solution for my use case- a complex app fully modularised

The idea behind this solution, is to have a reactive Value that monitors if the module has successfully completed its job. The observer in the module is wraped in a tryCatch. I guess I can wrap all reactives in the module with a tryCatch.
In case of a reactive or observer fails, then the module is unsuccessful, and the main server function in the app monitors this behavior and informs the user (see then `observeEvent(..)` in the main server function. Also, I return the success indicator from the module server. See `return(mod_success)`.

```
library(shiny)

counterButton <- function(id, label = "Counter") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("button"), label = label),
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("out"))
  )
}

counter <- function(input, output, session) {
  count <- reactiveVal(0)

  mod_success <- reactiveValues(
    success = TRUE,
    error = NULL
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
      
    tryCatch(
      expr = {
        count(count() + 1)
        if(count() == 4) {
          stop("You cannot count to: ", count())
        } 
      },
      error = function(errr){
        
        mod_success$success <- FALSE
        mod_success$error <- errr$message
        
      }
    )
    
    
  })
  
  output$out <- renderText({
    
    count()
    
  })
  
  return(mod_success)
  
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  counterButton("counter1", "Counter #1")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  res <- callModule(counter, "counter1")
  
  observeEvent(res$success,{
    
    if(isFALSE(res$success)){
      
      showNotification(paste0("Error: ", res$error), type = "error")
      
    }
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```